# Automatically style optional argument to proof environment?

Tags: theorems, amsthm, thmtools

With packages `amsthm` and `thmtools`, is there a way to cause the optional argument of every proof environment to be styled in a prescribed way — say to be sans serif and bold (in addition to the usual italic)?

This is to match the sans serif plus bold style that I'm using for theorem-like environment heads.

Comment: Do you mean both  theorem heads *and* the optional arguments should be bold sans serif?

Comment: I'm asking here about the *proof* environment, not theorem-like environments.

Comment: With `ntheorem`, you define your own proof environment, that's all – and the end-of-proof symbol will be automatically placed. Only the theorem-like environments declared *after* a series of declaration have the corresponding  features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to add

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

and then

```
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\proofheadfont}{}{}
\newcommand{\proofheadfont}{<whatever>}
```

As far as I know, using something like `\proofheadfont` instead of hardwiring `\itshape` is in the list of todos for the `amsthm` package.

For instance you may want

```
\newcommand{\proofheadfont}{\sffamily\bfseries\slshape}
```

Comment: Why `\itshape` in `\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\proofheadfont}{}{}` but `\slshape` in `\newcommand{\proofheadfont}{\sffamily\bfseries\slshape}`.

Comment: @murray Generally, sans serif fonts have slanted shape and italic is an alias.

Answer (score 0):

With `ntheorem`, you just have to write in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}

\theoremheaderfont{\sffamily\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\square}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

Comment: As indicated, I'm using `amsthm` which I believe has conflicts with `ntheorem`.

Comment: Sorry, I had misread the question: I thought you were asking either for `amsthm` or  `ntheorem`.